# How to fix null value to my backend side after submitting form data using Jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm currently working on inserting data from database, which I use in my url is the api of laravel, now I don't know why on my backend side returning value, but in my front end side when i try to alert the value is showing. Can you help me, or I just miss something on my backend thanks.

[image: Show output on alert]

I have here my function in my front end side,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#submit_contact_form').click(function(e) {

        var contact_subject_option = $('#contact_subject_option').val();
        var contact_transaction_date = $('#contact_transaction_date').val();
        var contact_first_name = $('#contact_first_name').val();
        var contact_lname = $('#contact_lname').val();
        var contact_contact_number = $('#contact_contact_number').val();
        var contact_email_address = $('#contact_email_address').val();
        var contact_store_number = $('#contact_store_number').val();
        var contact_transaction_number = $('#contact_transaction_number').val();
        var contact_content_article = $('#contact_content_article').val();

        alert(contact_subject_option);

        $.ajax({ 

            type:'POST',
            url:'/api/insert_contact',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            processData: true,
            data:{contact_subject_option: contact_subject_option,
                contact_transaction_date: contact_transaction_date,
                contact_first_name: contact_first_name,
                contact_lname: contact_lname,
                contact_contact_number: contact_contact_number,
                contact_email_address: contact_email_address,
                contact_store_number: contact_store_number,
                contact_transaction_number: contact_transaction_number,
                contact_content_article: contact_content_article

            },
            success:function(response) {
                if(response == 'Successfully Submitted')
                {
                     swal("Poof! Your message has been sent to the administrator.", {
                        icon: "success",
                      });
                }
            },
            error:function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })


        // if(contact_subject_option.length == 0 || 
        //  contact_transaction_date.length == 0 || 
        //  contact_first_name.length == 0 || 
        //  contact_lname.length == 0 || 
        //  contact_contact_number.length == 0 ||
        //  contact_email_address.length == 0 ||
        //  contact_store_number.length == 0 ||
        //  contact_transaction_number.length == 0 ||
        //  contact_content_article.length == 0)
        // {
        //   swal("Please fill up all fields..", {
     //            icon: "warning",
     //          });
        // }
        // else{


        // }



    })
})
```

Now in my backend side I use laravel Controller for my backend,

```
public function insert_contact(Request $request) {

  $subject  = $request->get('contact_subject_option');
  $fname = $request->get('contact_first_name');
  $lname = $request->get('contact_lname');
  $contact = $request->get('contact_contact_number');
  $email = $request->get('contact_email_address');
  $message = $request->get('contact_content_article');
  $storenum = $request->get('contact_store_number');
  $transactionnumber = $request->get('contact_transaction_number');
  $datetransaction = $request->get('contact_transaction_date');


  $now = new DateTime();

  DB::insert('INSERT INTO mail (firstname,lastname,email,contact,message,store_number,subject,transaction_date,transaction_number,status,created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ',[

        $fname,
        $lname,
        $email,
        $contact,
        $message,
        $storenum,
        $subject,
        $datetransaction,
        $transactionnumber,
        'Unread',
        $now

  ]);



    //  $data = array(
    //     'contents' => $message,
    //     'firstname' => $fname,
    //     'lastname' => $lname,
    //     'email' => $email,
    //     'transactionnumber' => $transactionnumber,
    //     'storenumber' => $storenum,
    //     'contactnumber' => $contact,
    //     'subject' => $subject,
    // );


    // \Mail::send('mailtext', $data,function($message){
    //     // $message->to('shiela.abundo@hiflyer.ca','Hiflyer');
    //     $message->to('george.muncal@hiflyer.ca','Hiflyer');
    //     $message->from('noreplyhfiofi@gmail.com','Hiflyer');
    //     $message->subject('New Notification');
    // });


   return response()->json('Successfully Submitted');


}
```

Comment: It seems your response from backend is sending JSON, try change the type to text or something

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by change the datatype, I use this

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
```